# How to select multiple variables using a join query in SQL

Tags: php, sql, join

I am trying to select the variables Username, SubjectName and Class from the class table, using a join query, however am unsure how to select multiple variables. Here is what I have tried...

```
<?php

session_start();

include_once('connection.php');

$user = $_SESSION["loggedin"];

// sets the variable user to the session variable "loggedin", which holds UserID
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT class.SubjectName as sub FROM userinclass
INNER JOIN class 
ON class.Class=userinclass.Class 
WHERE UserID=:UserID");

$stmt->bindParam(':UserID', $user);
$stmt->execute();

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
        echo($row["sub"]."<br>");



}
```

I have managed to select one variable (SubjectName) however am unsure how to select multiple variables. Here is the output, showing that it is currently working but just for one variable.

[image]

Comment: Just basic SQL... `SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM whatever INNER JOIN whateverElse...` ...surely if you've taken a SQL course or done any introductory tutorials you've seen examples of selecting more than one column? If you need to select from a specific table (especially if joined tables have columns with the same name) you can prefix the column name with the table name (like you've already done with `class.SubjectName`).